# onPageSelected callback for JetPack Compose Pager

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I am using JetPack Compose [Pager](https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/) from Accompanist and I'm wonder how do I know exactly when my page is Showed at screen. Like **onPageSelected** method from ViewPager.

Here is my code:

```
HorizontalPager(
        state = pagerState,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(MaterialTheme.colors.background)
    ) { page ->
         // This method reinvoked many times.

      }
```

'Cause currently each recomposition would invoke that callback method from Pager.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I think it will be better to use

```
LaunchedEffect(pagerState) {
    snapshotFlow { pagerState.currentPage }.collect { page ->
        // do your stuff with selected page
    }
}
```

Comment: To remove the duplicate state at the first composition use the flow with "distinctUntilChanged".

snapshotFlow { pagerState.currentPage }.distinctUntilChanged().collect { page ->
        // do your stuff with selected page
    }

Comment: From the snapshotFlow docs:
If the result of block is not equal to the previous result, the flow will emit that new result. (This behavior is similar to that of Flow.distinctUntilChanged.)

Comment: How to show list (LazyColumn) when page changed? Because in your above code, we can't use Composable inside that

Comment: This wrongly fires event is some cases. If you jump to tab 3 from tab 0, then you will get page change event for page 1 and page 2.  As it smooth scrolls from tab 0 to tab 3, it fires event for tab 2 as well.

Answer (score 12):

To complete @ysfcyln solution here is the official documentation :

https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/#reacting-to-page-changes

the full example there is :

```
val pagerState = rememberPagerState()

LaunchedEffect(pagerState) {
    // Collect from the a snapshotFlow reading the currentPage
    snapshotFlow { pagerState.currentPage }.collect { page ->
        AnalyticsService.sendPageSelectedEvent(page)
    }
}

VerticalPager(
    count = 10,
    state = pagerState,
) { page ->
    Text(text = "Page: $page")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your complete example solved my issues. I had added the LaunchedEffect inside the pager's content, which caused the analytics log to trigger more often than needed. Right now it's only triggered once. ...
I'd like to add that the event is only triggered when the new page would be active when releasing a drag & hold action on the pager, which is when the selected tabs also visually changes. In other words: drag & hold only a few pixels isn't considered a new screen event, but dragging the new page at least halfway on the screen is.

Answer (score 4):

This is a solution simpler than the one from the official documentation

```
LaunchedEffect(pagerState.currentPage) {
        // do your stuff with pagerState.currentPage
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution which worked quite well for me.
Extra thing with in it was **"distinctUntilChanged"**

```
LaunchedEffect(pagerState) {
    snapshotFlow {
        pagerState.currentPage
    }.distinctUntilChanged().collect { page ->
        // Now you can use selected page
        onPageChangeListener.invoke(page)
    }
}
```

Comment: Great addition! I also noticed multiple calls in my implementation. However, the post of Dagnogo solved it for me. Check out my comment why. As far as I can see distinctUntilChanged shouldn't be necessary in that case, although it's always good to have an additional safeguard!

Answer (score 1):

Use a variable to keep track

```
val trigger by remember { mutableStateOf (false) }
HorizontalPager(
        state = pagerState,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(MaterialTheme.colors.background)
    ) { page ->
         // Shown successfully,
         trigger = true //use at other places as a callback to change state
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do our tasks without any callbacks using `PagerState`.

```
val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = list.size)
        
        HorizontalPager(state = pagerState) { page ->
            // Our page content
            CardItemView(page, list[page])
        }

// Do your tasks based on the current page selected using pagerState.currentPage
        Toast.makeText(
            LocalContext.current,
            "Page selected ${pagerState.currentPage}",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()
```

Comment: That is not what "reacting" is. Bold answer, but completely misses the point.